# Karate - GraphQL - Validating nested JSON with arrays

Tags: json, automated-tests, cucumber, graphql, karate

I am having newb trouble validating nested JSON with arrays.  I have a GraphQL query that looks like this, it is the simplest of the ones I have.  I have changed the data as it is real production data but obv you can get the idea.  I realize from previous chats with @petersmith that * match results contains is a great way to go and I have also tried reading from a .json file but I must be formatting the json file wrong or something is off because I get error messages about javascript evaluation failed or no data found, etc.   I really just want to validate the datatypes, that the fields exist at all (claimNumber, claimStatus, totalPatientResponsibility, providerName, and memberName) and I want to pass in an invalid and/or null memberNumber and watch how it reacts. These seem so simple but I have only done it with REST and Cucumber using Ruby so now I seem to be having trouble.  Thanks!

```
    {

      getClaimHeadersList(memberNumber:"1111111111") {
        claimNumber
        claimStatus
        totalPatientResponsibility
        providerName
        memberName
      } 
}
```

The response back is the following:

```
{
"data": {
    "getClaimHeadersList": [
        {
            "claimNumber": "01-010111-111-11",
            "claimStatus": "Pended",
            "totalPatientResponsibility": 0.00,
            "providerName": "LastName, FirstName",
            "memberName": "LastName, FirstName M"
        },
        {
            "claimNumber": "01-010111-111-11",
            "claimStatus": "Pended",
            "totalPatientResponsibility": 0.00,
            "providerName": "LastName, FirstName",
            "memberName": "LastName, FirstName M"
        },
        {
            "claimNumber": "01-010111-111-11",
            "claimStatus": "Pended",
            "totalPatientResponsibility": 0.00,
            "providerName": "LastName, FirstName",
            "memberName": "LastName, FirstName M"
        },
        {
            "claimNumber": "01-010111-111-11",
            "claimStatus": "Posted",
            "totalPatientResponsibility": 0.00,
            "providerName": "LastName, FirstName",
            "memberName": "LastName, FirstName M"
        },
        {
            "claimNumber": "01-010111-111-11",
            "claimStatus": "Posted",
            "totalPatientResponsibility": 0.00,
            "providerName": "LastName, FirstName",
            "memberName": "LastName, FirstName M"
        },
        {
            "claimNumber": "01-010111-111-11",
            "claimStatus": "Posted",
            "totalPatientResponsibility": 0.00,
            "providerName": "LastName, FirstName",
            "memberName": "LastName, FirstName M"
        },
        {
            "claimNumber": "01-010111-111-11",
            "claimStatus": "Posted",
            "totalPatientResponsibility": 0.00,
            "providerName": "LastName, FirstName",
            "memberName": "LastName, FirstName M"
        },
        {
            "claimNumber": "01-010111-111-11",
            "claimStatus": "Posted",
            "totalPatientResponsibility": 0.00,
            "providerName": "LastName, FirstName",
            "memberName": "LastName, FirstName M"
        },
        {
            "claimNumber": "01-010111-111-11",
            "claimStatus": "Posted",
            "totalPatientResponsibility": 0.00,
            "providerName": "LastName, FirstName",
            "memberName": "LastName, FirstName M"
        },
        {
            "claimNumber": "01-010111-111-11",
            "claimStatus": "Posted",
            "totalPatientResponsibility": 0.00,
            "providerName": "LastName, FirstName",
            "memberName": "LastName, FirstName M"
        }
    ]
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can paste the entire section below into a fresh scenario and see it work.

```
* def response = 
"""
{
   "data":{
      "getClaimHeadersList":[
         {
            "claimNumber":"01-010111-111-11",
            "claimStatus":"Pended",
            "totalPatientResponsibility":0.00,
            "providerName":"LastName, FirstName",
            "memberName":"LastName, FirstName M"
         },
         {
            "claimNumber":"01-010111-111-11",
            "claimStatus":"Pended",
            "totalPatientResponsibility":0.00,
            "providerName":"LastName, FirstName",
            "memberName":"LastName, FirstName M"
         },
         {
            "claimNumber":"01-010111-111-11",
            "claimStatus":"Pended",
            "totalPatientResponsibility":0.00,
            "providerName":"LastName, FirstName",
            "memberName":"LastName, FirstName M"
         },
         {
            "claimNumber":"01-010111-111-11",
            "claimStatus":"Posted",
            "totalPatientResponsibility":0.00,
            "providerName":"LastName, FirstName",
            "memberName":"LastName, FirstName M"
         },
         {
            "claimNumber":"01-010111-111-11",
            "claimStatus":"Posted",
            "totalPatientResponsibility":0.00,
            "providerName":"LastName, FirstName",
            "memberName":"LastName, FirstName M"
         },
         {
            "claimNumber":"01-010111-111-11",
            "claimStatus":"Posted",
            "totalPatientResponsibility":0.00,
            "providerName":"LastName, FirstName",
            "memberName":"LastName, FirstName M"
         },
         {
            "claimNumber":"01-010111-111-11",
            "claimStatus":"Posted",
            "totalPatientResponsibility":0.00,
            "providerName":"LastName, FirstName",
            "memberName":"LastName, FirstName M"
         },
         {
            "claimNumber":"01-010111-111-11",
            "claimStatus":"Posted",
            "totalPatientResponsibility":0.00,
            "providerName":"LastName, FirstName",
            "memberName":"LastName, FirstName M"
         },
         {
            "claimNumber":"01-010111-111-11",
            "claimStatus":"Posted",
            "totalPatientResponsibility":0.00,
            "providerName":"LastName, FirstName",
            "memberName":"LastName, FirstName M"
         },
         {
            "claimNumber":"01-010111-111-11",
            "claimStatus":"Posted",
            "totalPatientResponsibility":0.00,
            "providerName":"LastName, FirstName",
            "memberName":"LastName, FirstName M"
         }
      ]
   }
}
"""
# get only the claims part out of the response as an array
* def claims =  get[0] response $..getClaimHeadersList
* print claims
# assert that there are exactly 10 claims
* match claims == '#[10]'
# assert that each claim has the exact values. note the special handling of 'claimStatus'
* match each claims == { "claimNumber":"01-010111-111-11", "claimStatus":"#? _ == 'Pended' || _ == 'Posted'", "totalPatientResponsibility":0.00, "providerName":"LastName, FirstName", "memberName":"LastName, FirstName M" }
# define a reusable 'schema' for the claim object, includes example of regex validation
* def claimSchema = { claimNumber: '#regex [0-1-]*', claimStatus: '#string', totalPatientResponsibility: '#number', providerName: '#string', memberName: '#string' }
# assert that each claim has all the keys expected and in the format expected
* match each claims == claimSchema
```

Comment: Perfect @PeterThomas!  I think I'm slowing getting how to do this with your examples. We also worked last night and got this working too so this is very helpful.     #Verify schema and data type
    * match each $response.data.getClaimHeadersList contains 
    
      """
      { 
      "claimNumber": '#regex [0-9]{2}-[0-9]{6}-[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{2}', 
      "claimStatus": '#regex (Pended|Posted)', 
      "totalPatientResponsibility": '#number', 
      "providerName": '#string', 
      "memberName": '#string' 
      }
      
    """