# Karate validate key of response: Json Object Schema or Empty array|object

Tags: karate

I have a list of users, some users have information about the Organization, others do not.

How can I validate if key is object schema (schemaOrganization) or just an empty array ?

Karate Code

@performance
Feature: API Example Call

```
Background:
    * url url
    * def user = call read('../GetToken.feature') { accessToken : response.token }
    * def schemaOrganization = { id: '#string', name: '#string'}
    * def schemaUser = { id: '#string', name: '#string', organization: '#(schemaOrganization)'}


Scenario: Auth -> api/v1/users
Given path 'api/v1/users'
And header Authorization = 'Bearer '+ user.token
And header Accept-Language = 'en'
When method get
Then status 200
* def data = response.data
* match each data == schemaUser
```

Already Tried :

- organization: '##[] #(schemaOrganization)'
- organization: '##[] schemaOrganization'
- organization: '#[] #schemaOrganization'

Response to be validated

```
{
    "data":[
        {
            "id":"123-123-123",
            "name":"example-name",
            "organization":[
                
            ]
        },
        {
            "id":"234-234-234",
            "name":"example-test",
            "organization":{
                "id":"org-123",
                "name":"example-org"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: for some reason, cannot add the karate code :

Comment: sorry your question is too complex for me, so I would prefer you make it simple. maybe someone else here can help. in the meantime please refer these answers: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71522605/143475 | https://stackoverflow.com/a/69847721/143475 | https://stackoverflow.com/a/49397347/143475

Comment: in the json response I wish to validate the organization key, it can be empty "organization":[]" , or be a schema of schemaOrganization .

Comment: please simplify your question then. otherwise I'm lost. can your example be just 2-3 lines ?

Comment: I do not know how I can simplify this question. The data response is a list of users which contains 3 keys (id,name,organization), I wish to validate this data as described above. id is string, name is string, organization can be an empty array OR a object with two keys. Not every user has organization, so it will be empty [], or it will have one organization with id and name object. 

How can i validate the organization key two accept this two options: empty array or object with two keys (id is string, name is string)